# Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm trying to get Laravel Homestead up and running. I believe I did everything as manual says. When I run vagrant up -command I get following error on OS X 10.9:

My Homestead.yaml file is following:

```
---
authorize: /Users/foo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/foo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

folders:
    - map: /Users/foo/projects
      to: /home/vagrant

sites:
    - map: site.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/site/public
```

And this is what I get while executing `vagrant up`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.1.6) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead/version/7/provider/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.1.6) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Homestead_default_1400312360757_29263
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/foo/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant => /Users/foo/Projects
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: tee: 
==> default: /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
==> default: : No such file or directory
==> default: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDkJjDXl7bdRlSQ453fsdOE7JZxk5x7b5XxeiQxS2Xitj1DiHTiVbNns71AflaNy+K2ev4SeazibpRrZnZ99Pnvd8XuJwScUZZzGaU/AsbQGDUNuQU4Wa047XhG28uHlfZNM/X3kMmsC73QtyByUDFadTAz2SjhwCBkatmpu8aSwOAtkNDTg+0QLql6yfIHaV5tn8DLBRhWWovpBcrU8aopG+7jgVpHghaIDq/1SmgclOt9paLZV333s9b8f/qCm4zc6sRFCvdKrIYgSutYnPTRkLRXm8ooX8/R6kvpxD6D6ss5e0+rDWgdxCthC2/pqWaZ/B76Pa7FXZlt9lDx7zAR foo@bar.com
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDkJjDXl7bdRlSQ453fsdOE7JZxk5x7b5XxeiQxS2Xitj1DiHTiVbNns71AflaNy+K2ev4SeazibpRrZnZ99Pnvd8XuJwScUZZzGaU/AsbQGDUNuQU4Wa047XhG28uHlfZNM/X3kMmsC73QtyByUDFadTAz2SjhwCBkatmpu8aSwOAtkNDTg+0QLql6yfIHaV5tn8DLBRhWWovpBcrU8aopG+7jgVpHghaIDq/1SmgclOt9paLZV333s9b8f/qCm4zc6sRFCvdKrIYgSutYnPTRkLRXm8ooX8/R6kvpxD6D6ss5e0+rDWgdxCthC2/pqWaZ/B76Pa7F5ZlX9lDx7zAR foo@bar.com
"

Stdout from the command:

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDkJjDXl7bdRlSQ453fsdOE7JZxk5x7b5XxeiQxS2Xitj1DiHTiVbNns71AflaNy+K2ev4SeazibpRrZnZ99Pnvd8XuJwScUZZzGaU/AsbQGDUNuQU4Wa047XhG28uHlfZNM/X3kMmsC73QtyByUDFadTAz2SjhwCBkatmpu8aSwOAtkNDTg+0QLql6yfIHaV5tn8DLBRhWWovpBcrU8aopG+7jgVpHghaIDq/1SmgclOt9paLZV333s9b8f/qCm4zc6sRFCvdKrIYgSutYnXTRkLRXm8oor8/R6kvpxD6D6sX5e0+rDWgdxCthC2/pqWaZ/B76Pa7F5Zlt9lDxXzAR foo@bar.com


Stderr from the command:

tee: /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Map your `projects` directory to something else than `/home/vagrant`:

```
folders:
- map: /Users/foo/projects
  to: /home/vagrant/projects
```

This should fix your problem and you probably don't want your vagrant's config files (`.ssh`, `.bashrc`, etc) synced back to your local `projects` directory anyway.

Also your `keys` property should be set to private key, not public.

Comment: This worked. I first had to `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` again to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at original Homestead.yaml again, you'll see that:

`authorize` needs your public key (id_rsa.pub)

`keys` needs your privte key (id_rsa)

Answer (score 0):

keys should be:

keys: - /Users/foo/.ssh/id_rsa
not 
keys: - /Users/foo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 0):

Homestead is just an implementation of vagrant.

Try:

> homestead up

If this still doesn't work, try

> homestead destroy && homestead up

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion here based on my own learning experience. Homestead provides a nice and neat way for beginners to work on Laravel Framework in no time. However, I think the vagrant settings and weird environment is not straight forward to me.

I believe everyone has to work with the real Server and Laravel environment eventually. Therefore, I decided to give up homestead and simply install Ubuntu on VirtualBox. Then, I followed official instructions [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation) and installed my Laravel pretty easily.

Just for your information. Just go straight to the real Laravel system instead of Homestead.